# How to escape single quote within string variable in NCalc.Expression - Backslash didn't work

Tags: c#, string, expression, ncalc

I am using NCalc.Expression to evaluate a condition which involves comparison with string values that contain single quote within them. In NCalc, string is represented using single quote instead of double quotes.

Ex:

```
[variable1]=='Sample's Data'
```

In order to escape the single quote, I tried appending a backlash like this -

```
[variable1]=='Sample\'s Data'
```

But when this is assigned to a string variable, it removes the backslash as -

`[variable1]=='Sample's Data'`

and after assigning this to the Expression constructor, it throws an error when evaluated that text after the second single quote "s Data" is not recognized.

When I try appending two backslashes as below -

`[variable1]=='Sample\\'s Data'`,

this is assigned to a string variable as

`"[variable1]=='Sample\'s Data'"`

but evaluating it doesn't throw the exception but fails the comparison since the data is

`"[variable1]=='Sample's Data'"`

without the backslash.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you try with 4 `\ `?

Comment: I answered with the possible ways of escaping a quote in an expression. If these are not what you're looking for, then please give a minimal, reproducable example that we can paste into VS and use to help fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way is to use the Unicode code point for `'` which is [U+0027](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm)

```
var e = new Expression(@"'Sample\u0027s Data'");
var evaluated = e.Evaluate();
```

[Source](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

Or simply:

```
var e = new Expression(@"'Sample\'s Data'");
var evaluated = e.Evaluate();
```

Without a verbatim string:

```
var e = new Expression("'Sample\\'s Data'");
var evaluated = e.Evaluate();
```

This gives `true`:

```
var e = new Expression("variable=='Sample\\'s Data'");
e.Parameters["variable"] = "Sample's Data";
var evaluated = e.Evaluate();
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but other than the \u0027 suggestion, how are the others different than what he already tried?

Comment: Just showing the ways of escaping the quote in an expression. Maybe I don't understand his question then. I thought that's what he has a problem with. If not then he should give a code example I can copy into VS and fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The Unicode approach worked fine. I had tried the other options but they didn't work due to the exception I mentioned initially. Appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki https://ncalc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=values&referringTitle=Home#strings

> You can escape special characters using \\, \', \n, \r, \t.

Comment: That link is soooo dead; this one seems slightly newer https://github.com/ncalc/ncalc/wiki/Values